# mysql_fetch_array returns an array and the number "1"

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a problem with mysql_fetch_array. I'm trying to do this:

```
if(count(mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($peticion)))) {
    array_push($errores, $texto['conta_existe']);
}
```

The previous code should detect if mysql_fetch_array found a row in my database and, if it found at least one, an array should be pushed. Problem is that if I haven't got anything in my db, fetch_array returns the number "1".

I tried to find what's happening with this peace of code:

```
$arrayc = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($peticion), MYSQL_NUM);
echo 'PRINT_R: ';
echo print_r($arrayc);
echo '<br>COUNT: ';
echo count($arrayc);
```

And returns this:

> PRINT_R: Array ( [0] => FLEREX [conta] => FLEREX ) 1
>
> COUNT: 2

I don't understand why there's that number one there, after the array. The previous quote was returned with only one row, to show you the array; but if there's not any row in the db, this is what I get:

> PRINT_R: 1
>
> COUNT: 1

I don't know where comes from that one, but is always there.

Thanks for reading and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: `echo print_r($arrayc);`.... `print_r($arrayc)` outputs the value of `$arrayc`, and returns a booleam `true`; that you're then echoing that returned value, and which is displayed as `1`

Comment: remove echo here `echo print_r($arrayc)`

Comment: Just a heads-up, start using PDO or mysqli functions. They're safer and mysql_* functions are (going to be?) deprecated.

Comment: mysql_* ARE deprecated as of PHP 5.5

Comment: @Bono the extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0.

Comment: When you call `print_r()` with just one argument, the contents of the parameter (usually an array) is passed to STDOUT. In this case, it also returns a boolean TRUE (which is what you're seeing as `1`). To avoid this, set the second parameter to `TRUE`, like so: `print_r($arrayc, TRUE);`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try mysql_num_rows instead of count and delete the mysql_fetch_array

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_fetch_array` doesn't return an array of all the results, it just returns the next row of results, or `false` if there are no more results. So `count()` returns the number of columns multiplied by 2 (because the array contains both numeric and associative entries).

Use `mysql_num_rows` to get the number of rows in the results.

```
if (mysql_num_rows(mysql_query($peticion))) {
```

Comment: We posted our answers at the same time.